# Emacs New File Confirmation during Find-File Completion

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

Some Emacs package I use has turned *off* the find-file confirmation for choosing a new non-existing file that matches parts of existing file-names shown during completion. I want this confirmation back to the default. What customization option regulates this behaviour?

Example:

- `M-x` `find-file`
- Enter letter `a`
- Pressing `TAB` now gives two candidates: `a1` and `a2`
- Just pressing `Return` ***should now query me to confirm through an extra*** `Return`. Indicated by a `[Confirm]` at the end of the minibuffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

check the value of the variable `confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer`